# Sending data to server via URL without webserver

Tags: serial-communication

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
This example sets up a server that listens to a port and echoes the received data.
I want to be able to pass data to it via URL in a manner such as typing ip:port;data.
Is that thing possible in any way?
I don't want to have any user interface at all. Just type in the address, port and data in the URL and the server receives the data.

Comment: What do you intend to do with any user requested/posted data if a server isn't going to do anything?

Comment: @BigChris I'll echo it, just so I know it is working. Later on I'll add a mechanism to determine the appropriate action in response to the data

Comment: What are you going to use to echo it? JavaScript? Everything else is "server-side"

Comment: @BigChris Look at the example, nothing is changed in it (Except for the ip and port of the server). The example will show you how it receives the data and how it echoes it. But it doesn't matter how I will echo it, I just want to know how can a user send the data. Right now I don't care if the data will not be dealt with I just want to be able to send a data without any user interface, straight from the URL.